# How to deal with overlapping black parts of Light mask textures?

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, glsl, opengl-es2

I am using this masking texture for a dynamic lighting effect in my game:
[image]

It looks beautiful until two lights begin to overlap:

[image: edsmage description here]

This is obviously because the textures are overlapping when I draw them to the light map `FrameBuffer`.

```
lightFbo.begin();
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            g.begin();

                for(Entity ent : entities){
                    if(ent instanceof Fireball)g.draw(light,ent.x - tlightSize / 2.5f,ent.y - tlightSize * 0.25f, tlightSize, tlightSize);
                }
            if(p instanceof FireCharacter){
                g.draw(light,p.x - lightSize / 2.5f,p.y - lightSize * 0.25f, lightSize, lightSize);

            }
g.end();
lightFbo.end();
```

I use the buffer texture from this map when I draw my actual game:'

```
g.setShader(lightingShader);
g.begin();
lightFbo.getColorBufferTexture().bind(1); //u_lightmap
light.bind(0)//u_texture
//draw things
g.end();
```

I don't want these to overlap, I want the light circles to merge without the border cutting in front of them. I tried making the black transparent in GIMP on the light texture but that made no difference. Here is the lighting shader:

**Vertex Shader**

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    vColor = a_color;
    vTexCoord = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;     
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

varying LOWP vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

//texture samplers
uniform sampler2D u_texture; //diffuse map
uniform sampler2D u_lightmap;   //light map (frame buffer texture)

//additional parameters for the shader
uniform vec2 resolution; //resolution of screen
uniform LOWP vec4 ambientColor; //ambient RGB, alpha channel is intensity 

void main() {
vec4 diffuseColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);
vec2 lighCoord = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy);
vec4 light = texture2D(u_lightmap, lighCoord);

vec3 ambient = ambientColor.rgb * ambientColor.a;
vec3 intensity = ambient + light.rgb;
vec3 finalColor = diffuseColor.rgb * intensity;

gl_FragColor = vColor * vec4(finalColor, diffuseColor.a);
}
```

My only ideas are using Gdx.gl.glSetBlendFunc(); and changing the blending source and dest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I solved it:

**1.** Make sure `glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND_COLOR);` is on and the blend function is `Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA,GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

**2.** Edit the light texture in something like GIMP to double check that your background is transparent.

**3.** ***MOST IMPORTANT*** Make sure the lightFramebuffer is `Format.RGBA4444` or `Format.RGBA8888` to support transparency.